# Ansible conditional check failed

Tags: ansible

Need Ansible help on error. Same ansible module/task getting error in 1 environment and completely fine in another. Dunno what the causes are. Here's the error:

```
fatal: [hostname.com]: FAILED! => {
  "msg": "The conditional check ''failed' in prereq.stdout_lines' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('failed' in prereq.stdout_lines): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if 'failed' in prereq.stdout_lines %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).
  Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable"
}
```

here's task snippet:

```
- name: Check for patch conflicts
  shell: ./patch_command {{ patch_directory }}/{{ patchid }}
  environment: "{{ env }}"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ patch_directory }}"
  when: patchid != 'nopatch'
  register: prereq
  failed_when: "'failed' in prereq.stdout_lines"
```

Comment: looks like you should remove the " " from the failed_when statement.

Answer (score 0):

By any chance, is it possible that the prereq variable is not defined or has an empty prereq.stdout_lines in the environment where you get the error?

Can you add a 

`- debug:
    var: prereq`

in that environment, and post the output here?

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar error, same task in almost equal hosts (same OS). One runs fine, the other server gives me an error.

the task:

```
- name: "Configuring API url"
  set_fact:
   api_url: "{% if env == 'prd' %}{{ fqdn_base }}{% else %}{{env}}-{{ fqdn_base }}{% endif %}"

- debug: var=api_url

- name: Check API URL connect to the right API apis
  uri:
    url: https://api-{{ api_url }}/features/base_url
    return_content: yes
  register: webpage
  until: "api_url|string in webpage.content"
  delay: 5
  retries: 10
```

The server that fails gives me this output

```
TASK [api : Configuring API url] ***********************************************
ok: [p-xxxxx.yyyyy.local]

TASK [api : debug] *************************************************************
ok: [p-xxxxx.yyyyy.local] => {
    "api_url": "roca.yyyyy.com"
}

TASK [api : Check API URL connect to the right API] ****************************
FAILED - RETRYING: Check API URL connect to the right API (10 retries left).
fatal: [p-xxxxx.yyyyy.local]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'api_url|string in webpage.content' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (api_url|string in webpage.content): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if api_url|string in webpage.content %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable"}
    to retry, use: --limit @/builds/iristrace/api/deploy/api.retry
```